# TFS source control - merge new version (hot fix) with our changes

Tags: tfs, merge, branch, hotfix

I've found similar question here: [TFS /Source Control: How to manage hotfixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358568/tfs-source-control-how-to-manage-hotfixes)
But the answer doesn't suit me.

So the problem is that:

1. I have an application created by company "A".
2. I put it on TFS
3. Then I have to do some changes in code (branding, change some functionality etc).
4. I release my version.
5. Now company "A" says: "Hey, there are some bugs. We have fixed them. You can download the codes now".
6. So I download the codes.

And what next? I need to have my changes and hotfixes. So I did:

1. Make branch out of Main and called it "hotfix"
2. Checkout the whole hotfix branch
3. Paste codes from company "A" into my hotfix branch folder on my harddrive.
4. Check-in whole hotfix branch
5. Merge hotfix branch with main branch.

As the result I got only new codes from company "A". All my changes are missing.

So how should I do it properly?

Comment: Did the company A edit code on Main branch and when you merge from Hotfix branch to Main, is there any conflicts? Did you choose the "Keep target" when merge?

Comment: Company A works on completely different source control (SVN). So first I get codes from their SVN, then I remove codes from SVN version control and then I put the codes into TFS.

Comment: So all of you are working in TFS or they still using SVN? Could you please describe your issue with more details. You can't see what you changed in the Main branch or Hotfix branch?

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to this document to use branches in a better way.
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/branching-strategies-with-tfvc#servicing-and-release-isolation.

When you merge from the Hotfix branch to Main, you could get the latest version of the Main branch before you merge.

Comment: It looks like it does not work. Every time I lose my changes.